# Get user's organisation details (e.g. idenitifier and/or domain) from googleapis without userinfo.profile scope

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-oauth

I'm looking to retrieve an identifier of some description that allows me to see what Google organisation a user is a part of. The purpose of this identifier is to identify when multiple users are part of the same Google organisation.

At the moment here is what I'm doing:

```js
// oauth2 stuff above
const userInfo = await oauth2.userinfo.get({});
const {
  data: { email, hd },
} = userInfo;
```

This returns the domain (`hd`) but it requires the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile` scope. This scope requests access to *all the user's public info* including gender, name, profile pic and more.

Is there a better way to do this? Is there a scope that I can use that only asks to access the `organisation id` in Google or something?

This identifier needs to be unique to the overall Gsuite/Workspace organisation (or, obviously empty/null if it's a gmail account, not a Gsuite/Workspace account).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you request the scopes `openid email`, then the `hd` claim is included in the ID Token and you don't need to call the UserInfo endpoint at all.

And yes, checking the `hd` claim is the right approach to find out whether a user account is managed by Cloud Identity/Workspace.